# Передача аргументов в makefile из командной строки

Tags: makefile

Возможно ли передать аргументы в makefile из командной строки?

Например, вот makefile:

```
    all:
            gcc -m32 -O2 -std=gnu11 -Wall -Werror -Wno-pointer-sign (FILEname)
```

Есть желание, чтобы `FILEname` передавался из командной строки.

Answer (score 2):

Makefile

```
all:
    gcc -m32 -O2 -std=gnu11 -Wall -Werror -Wno-pointer-sign $(filename)
```

Запуск

```
make filename=hello.c
```